# nav not working properly in ie8 - no background colour + sub menus dont have inline style

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, nav

Relatively new to CSS and html5, I have used [this](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu) tutorial to create a simple pure CSS/html5 drop down menu. In IE8 it does not work properly unfortunately. 
I have used the HTML shiv and given all the html5 elements a `display:block` style in my stylesheet.

The dropdown works and onhover colors appear for submenus in ie8 but the is no background color and the submenus don't position properly or appear as inline style even though I specified this in the CSS.

```
nav ul li{
          display: inline-table; <-- being ignored
          float:left;   <-- being ignored
         }
```

and for the background color for the list (used colorzilla to generate gradient code below)

```
nav ul {

background: rgb(87,179,229); Old browsers - doesn't work
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(87,179,229,1) 0%, rgba(29,81,145,1) 50%,     rgba(15,52,96,1) 51%, rgba(18,61,114,1) 74%, rgba(89,122,165,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(87,179,229,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(29,81,145,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(15,52,96,1)), color-stop(74%,rgba(18,61,114,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(89,122,165,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(87,179,229,1) 0%,rgba(29,81,145,1) 50%,rgba(15,52,96,1) 51%,rgba(18,61,114,1) 74%,rgba(89,122,165,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(87,179,229,1) 0%,rgba(29,81,145,1) 50%,rgba(15,52,96,1) 51%,rgba(18,61,114,1) 74%,rgba(89,122,165,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(87,179,229,1) 0%,rgba(29,81,145,1) 50%,rgba(15,52,96,1) 51%,rgba(18,61,114,1) 74%,rgba(89,122,165,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(87,179,229,1) 0%,rgba(29,81,145,1) 50%,rgba(15,52,96,1) 51%,rgba(18,61,114,1) 74%,rgba(89,122,165,1) 100%); /* W3C */filter:     
/* To try and make it work in IE6-9 */
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#57b3e5', endColorstr='#597aa5',GradientType=0 ); /* To try and make it work in IE6-9 */
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#57b3e5', endColorstr='#597aa5',GradientType=0 ); /* To try and make it work in IE6-9 */



box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 0px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table; <-- Not ignored in ie8

                }
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could make it work in IE8? I read that ie8 doesn't allow child elements to inherit styles in the nav/list hierarchy, but surely if I explicitly specify styles, they should work anyway? Is it that ie8 still doesn't recognise the nav/ul tags properly?

All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML5 shim is working, since it's respecting the declaration in `nav ul`, which means something else is wrong.

Is there any particular reason you're using `inline-table` for the `li` elements? It might be worth trying `display: block` for the `li`s and see if that works for the same effect you're trying to achieve. Alternatively, you may be able to change it to `display: table-cell` and remove the float.

Also, it might be worth looking at the page in IE9 for the developer tools. You can set it to "IE8 mode", which will give you a pretty accurate approximation of IE8, plus the ability to see what IE sees (I've found some differences, but not enough to overcome the usefulness of IE9's developer tools). It's possible something else is overriding your setting (such as a more specific declaration in an IE-only stylesheet).

On a side note, `display: inline-table` (or most of the display properties other than block and inline) [doesn't work in IE7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display). Just a head's up in case you need to support IE7.

Comment: I was using the `inline table` for the `li` elements because I wanted the dropdowns to appear spread horizontally rather than just being a vertical list. Is there some (other) way to get the dropdown to appear spread horizontally (with the same width as the menu bar above it)? I am playing with the ie8 developer tools now, thanks for that. I tried changing to `display: table-cell`, and I get background color for the menubar itself now, but in ie8, it stops being a horizontal list. Any ideas to get it to be horizontal? I would vote you up but I don't have enough rep.....

Comment: @nme32 - There are several ways to get them to display horizontally, including adding `float: left` *or* `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` to the list items. I recommend checking out A List Apart's [Taming Lists](http://alistapart.com/article/taminglists/) and [Suckerfish](http://alistapart.com/article/dropdowns), as well as HTMLDog's [Son of Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) articles for more information (note: Suckerfish and SoS are getting a little dated overall, but the CSS techniques for making horizontal lists are still sound).

Comment: Managed to get the menubar to display horizontally including `float:left` to `nav ul li` element, but can't get the sub menus to align with with their parent button.Also had to remove all [filter statements](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6548) to get sub menus to overflow properly in IE7.The links you gave are useful,but can't figure out how todo inline submenus with em.Hopefully hybridising [this](http://www.cssnewbie.com/horizontal-dropdown-menus/) and my original guide I can do it.May have to recode from scratch :'(. will write here if/when successful. thanks shauna

Comment: @nme32 - The Suckerfish articles should help guide you. Note how they use `position: relative` and `position: absolute` to make submenus. You just then need to adjust the `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and/or `right` values for the submenus to line them up properly. As long as your markup is a nested list, it should be fairly straightforward once you figure out how the positioning works.

Comment: I tried using `position:relative` on `nav ul li` and `nav ul ul` elements to align sub menus, however although I can position the sub menus, using the `relative` value causes the entire menubar to expand with the drop down, meaning I have a massive blue rectangle surrounding my grey vertical list.... I need to find a way to make the sub menus overflow and not cause the entire menu to expand with them when they appear. Trying to figure this out now..

Comment: Use `position: absolute` for the sub menus. See also [A List Apart's Positioning 101](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101).

Answer (score 0):

add this js code in your page 
it defines html5 elements in ie

```
(function(){if(!/*@cc_on!@*/0)return;var e = "abbr,article,aside,audio,bb,canvas,datagrid,datalist,details,dialog,eventsource,figure,footer,header,hgroup,mark,menu,meter,nav,output,progress,section,time,video".split(','),i=e.length;while(i--){document.createElement(e[i])}})()
```

Comment: In to the header? Thanks. Edit: I added it into the header in `<script></script>` tags, but still no change.

Comment: yup 
under `<script>...</script>`

Comment: should I remove `<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>`? I have references to a few other scripts I thought would help, should I remove them too or would it make no difference?

Comment: i think both do same thing

Comment: No joy with that I'm afraid. Thanks anyway.